# crc32 missing when trying to compile (MinGW)

Tags: windows, compiler-errors, package

I'm trying to compile firmware for a device called particle photon locally and I follow the instructions here: https://github.com/spark/firmware/tree/latest
Went through the guide and tried to hit "make" on my windows machine. It complained on missing crc32.

So what package through MinGW do I have to install to get crc32 functionality?

> C:\particle-firmware-develop\user>make fatal: Not a git repository (or
>   any of the parent directories): .git process_begin:
>   CreateProcess(NULL, which crc32, ...) failed.
>   ../build/common-tools.mk:26: *** "crc32 tool is not found".  Stannar.
>
> C:\particle-firmware-develop\user>

Comment: You need mingw-developer-toolkit, and you must run it within bash/msys console (crc32 is a perl script)